# Failed to retrieve data from the database. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 1370 ] in Crystal Reports using ASP.ET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have goggled alot but did't find any solution. 
I am using Visual studio 2012 with My Sql as Database and Crystal reports.
I have deployed web application on WINDOWS SERVER 2008 and when i access from remote it give me following error message, as given in following screen.

[image]

**i am using the following code**

```
    string databaseName = "hr";
        string serverName = "192.168.137.6";
        string userID = "userID";
        string pass = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;

            ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/GeneralEmpReports/test.rpt");
            reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
            reportDocument.SetParameterValue("D", tbx_ddoCode.Text.ToUpper());
            reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(userID, pass, serverName, databaseName);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        }
```

Here i want to add that only ***Stored Procedures*** gives me the above error, if i made a report from ***Tables*** then no error and execute perfectly. I have checked stored procedure through Navicat tool (GUI Administrative tool for mysql) , it works fine.

I have added the following connection on server through control Panel==>Administrative tools ==>Data Source (ODBC) as shown in following figure.
[image]

Comment: Where is your connection establishment code ?

Comment: connection is established through User DSN from Administratice tool in control panel

Comment: Control Panel == > Administrative tools == > Data source (ODBC) here i have created a user DSN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, i came to know that i am doing mistake in ***Server Name***,
Server Name should be ***DSN*** name not ***IP address***. Create ***System DSN*** name on your production server same as given in development computer as in following.

[image]

**Data source Name :** DSN_Name

**TCP/IP Server :**   In development PC give it blank it means **localhost** but in development Server give IP address.

**User:** UserName

**Paswword:**  Password

**Database:** Database Name

Following is the code which works fine.

```
 string databaseName = "hr";
    string serverName = "hr_domain"; // DSN Name
    string userID = "xxxxxxx";
    string pass = "xxxxxxxx";
    protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/GeneralEmpReports/test.rpt");
        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
        reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(userID, pass, serverName, databaseName);
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("D", tbx_ddoCode.Text.ToUpper());
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    }
```